# passing parameters through this.props.history.push('/xyz) in react router

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I need to pass certain parameters from one component to another component using react router in react

```
clicked =()=>{
         //alert('clicked');
         this.props.history.push('/roles')// we need to pass paramters through this
    }
```

We need to retrieve the paramters passed from this in the component where the roles is pointing to ?

Comment: Yeah shubham.I will try to look into the answer and figure out.I

Comment: Let me know if you are still unable to get to the solution